# Is there a good way to ignore comment-only changes in Magento version upgrades?

Tags: upgrade, git, phpstorm

Since Magento changes the year in the comments of ever single file, does anyone have a recommended or battle-tested way to properly audit the actual changes for each version?

Ideally a solution using Git or even some method via PhpStorm would be ideal.  At the moment the best solution I have is to use DiffMerge and create a custom ruleset to try and ignore PHP comments with the regex `(^ *\*)|(^\/\*)|(^\/\/)` which isn't ideal or 100% accurate and requires a separate diff process from my normal tools.

As a side question... does anyone know why Magento insists on updating all of the comments in this manner?  It is incredibly frustrating and seemingly unnecessary.  I'm hoping I am just missing some easy solution!  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why do you want to ignore them?

Comment: When doing an upgrade we need to identify everything that changed so we can review and fix any custom code and theme files as well as verify any 3rd party extensions are compatible and patched.

Comment: Wouldn't making a copy of website and upgrading it be a better option?

Comment: This is for auditing the code so we can assure the new security updates and other features that changed are implemented in any customized code as part of our initial upgrade process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever since Magento version [2.2.0](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8648), Magento no longer incorporates the current year in their copyright notices.  Magento backported this into version [2.1.13](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/160331e273e738193ef1b6b4e79ad5bb5f1081b2) as well.